# PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type ... Use setObject() (I am using it!)

Tags: java, database, rest, jersey, uuid

Hi maybe I can get some help here once again! I am testing a server to connect to a DB and so far it works and I can insert UUID Data. But when I try to migrate to another project, the same function doesn't work as it should. It doesn't save the data in the DB...I have checked everything but there must be something I haven't notice that's bugging... any help or direction will be greatly appreciate.

```
package ...


imports ...

@Path("/UserPoints")
public class getNewPoints {

    @Path("/getNewPoints")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)

    public Response getUserPoints(@QueryParam("user_id") UUID username,
                                   @QueryParam("point_id") int pointId,
                                   @QueryParam("earned_points") int points
    ) {
        try {
            if (username == null)
                throw new Exception("Invalid data");
            else {
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                Connection connection  = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL,DBUSER, DBPASS);
                PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQLQuery.getQuery("new_earned_points"));
                statement.setObject(1, UUID.fromString(username.toString()));  //THIS WORKS IN THE ORIGINAL PROJECT
                statement.setInt(2, pointId);
                statement.setInt(3, points);
                statement.executeUpdate();
                statement.close();
                System.out.println("points.. on get New Points... " + points);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("new points added to user " + pointId).build();
    }

}
```

**Solution**  After checking the stacktrace I notice the postgresql version was an old one... so I updated it in the pom and then it worked.

Comment: Is the parameter _username_ or _userid_? And is _username_ a String or a UUID? Because it does not make a lot of sense to call _toString()_ on a UUID and then generate a new UUID from that.

Comment: It is user_id in the DB, I changed the paramateres from the public Response to match user_id but still I get the error....

Comment: Surely you can replace the mountain of code you've presented to a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  The exercise of doing so will be useful to you, and the result will be helpful not only to those of us who may want to answer the question, but also to everyone who later reads it.

Comment: Thank you I am sorry for this... BTW I fixed it it was just the version of posgresql in the pom...  sorry again for the mountain of code

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting the answer which was edited into the original question:

> **Solution** After checking the stacktrace I notice the postgresql version was an old one... so I updated it in the pom and then it worked.